# Word count without footnotes

Tags: word-count

Do you know how can I count the words without footnotes? I saw that there was a general solution for counting words without specific environments but that seems very cumbersome. I was wondering if there wasn't anything easier. I have used the statistics tab to see the word count and it includes all my footnotes; however, many journals in my field have a word limit for the body of the text and then a separate word limit for footnotes). 
Thanks

Comment: I recommend texcount: http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/whatitdoes.html (also described in above link) it may also help to know your editor

Comment: Thanks very much! I actually was looking for word count in LyX. Is there anybody who knows about that?

Answer (score 1):

If you (re)define `\footnote` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Alice has a cat\footnote{Bob has a blob}

\def\footnote#1{}
Alice has a cat\footnote{Bob has a blob}

\end{document}
```

the words in footnotes will not appear. Then you can choose a suitable tool, e.g. http://felix-cat.com/tools/wordcount/ to count words in the obtained PDF file. Of course, if your journals suggest another tools, they will be preferable.